# Group rows in Pandas dataframe, apply custom function and store results in a new dataframe as rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe **df_org** with three columns - Index (integer), Titles (string) and Dates (date).

[image]

I have a method **process_title(text)**, which takes a string as input and tokenize, remove stop words and lemmatize the input string and returns the words as a list.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def process_title(text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text.lower())
    try:
        tokens.remove("google")
        tokens.remove("search")
        tokens.remove("-")
    except:
        pass

    lemm_tokens = list(map(lemmatizer.lemmatize,tokens))
    without_stop = [word for word in lemm_tokens if word not in stop_words]
    return without_stop
```

I want a new dataframe which contains three columns - Word(string), Frequency(integer), Date(date). The **Word** column contain words(single word) from the list returned by process_title(text), the **Frequency** column contains the frequency of that word appearing on a given date and **Date** column contains the date.

```
    ---------------------------------------
    |  Word    | Frequency     |   Date   |
    ---------------------------------------
    | computer | 1             |2021-08-01|
    | science  | 1             |2021-08-01|
    | something| 5             |2021-08-02|
.....
```

How can I group the **df_org** dataframe along date and create the new dataframe? Changes can be made to the **process_title(text)** method without compromising the end requirement.

Comment: Please post some sample of your data and the expected output plus what have you tried so far

Comment: Indeed. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataFrame.explode` method, followed by `groupby` and `size`:

I am going to just use a simple `.str.split` instead of your function, as I don't know where `word_tokenize` comes from.

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['Hello World', 'Foo Bar'], 'date': ['2021-01-12T20:00', '2021-02-10T22:00']})

In [3]: df['words'] = df['title'].apply(lambda s: process_title(str(s)))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
         title              date           words
0  Hello World  2021-01-12T20:00  [Hello, World]
1      Foo Bar  2021-02-10T22:00      [Foo, Bar]

In [5]: exploded = df.explode('words')

In [6]: exploded
Out[6]:
         title              date  words
0  Hello World  2021-01-12T20:00  Hello
0  Hello World  2021-01-12T20:00  World
1      Foo Bar  2021-02-10T22:00    Foo
1      Foo Bar  2021-02-10T22:00    Bar

In [7]: exploded.groupby(['date', 'words']).size()
Out[7]:
date              words
2021-01-12T20:00  Hello    1
                  World    1
2021-02-10T22:00  Bar      1
                  Foo      1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you please modify the code to use the process_title() method? I used nltk libraries. The method returns a list of strings.

Comment: So does `str.split`, so it should be directly applicable

Comment: `df['words'] = df['title'].apply(lambda s: process_title(str(s)))`
does the trick